# ParquetProtoWriters creates an unreadable parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

My .proto file contains one field of map type.

```
Message Foo {
    ...
    ...
    map<string, uint32> fooMap = 19; 
}
```

I'm consuming messages from Kafka source and trying to write the messages as a parquet file to S3 bucket.
The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
  val basePath = "s3a:// ..."

  env
    .fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "source")
    .map(x => toJavaProto(x))
    .sinkTo(
      FileSink
        .forBulkFormat(basePath, ParquetProtoWriters.forType(classOf(Foo)))
        .withOutputFileConfig(
          OutputFileConfig
            .builder()
            .withPartPrefix("foo")
            .withPartSuffix(".parquet")
            .build()
        )
        .build()
    )
    .setParallelism(1)
  env.execute()
```

The result is that a parquet file was actually written for S3, but the file appears to be corrupted. When I try to read the file using the Avro / Parquet Viewer plugin I can see this error:

> Unable to process file
> .../Downloads/foo-9366c15f-270e-4939-ad88-b77ee27ddc2f-0.parquet
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: REPEATED not supported
> outside LIST or MAP. Type: repeated group fooMap = 19 {   optional
> binary key (STRING) = 1;   optional int32 value = 2; }    at
> org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertFields(AvroSchemaConverter.java:277)
> at
> org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroReadSupport.prepareForRead(AvroReadSupport.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.initialize(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:185)
> at
> org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.initReader(ParquetReader.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.read(ParquetReader.java:135)
> at
> uk.co.hadoopathome.intellij.viewer.fileformat.ParquetFileReader.getRecords(ParquetFileReader.java:99)
> at
> uk.co.hadoopathome.intellij.viewer.FileViewerToolWindow$2.doInBackground(FileViewerToolWindow.java:193)
> at
> uk.co.hadoopathome.intellij.viewer.FileViewerToolWindow$2.doInBackground(FileViewerToolWindow.java:184)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Flink version 1.15
proto 2

Answer (score 1):

There are some breaking changes in `parquet-format` and `parquet-mr`. I'm not familiar with Flink, but I guess you have to configure `org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.protobuf.ParquetProtoWriters` to generate a correct format.

---

I used `parquet-mr` directly and encountered the same issue. An avro parquet reader is unable to read the parquet file generated by the following code:

```java
import org.apache.parquet.proto.ProtoParquetWriter;
import org.apache.parquet.proto.ProtoWriteSupport;

...

var conf = new Configuration();
ProtoWriteSupport.setWriteSpecsCompliant(conf, false);

var builder = ProtoParquetWriter.builder(file)
        .withMessage(Xxx.class)
        .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.GZIP)
        .withWriteMode(Mode.OVERWRITE)
        .withConf(conf);

try (var writer = builder.build()) {
    writer.write(pb.toBuilder());
}
```

If the config value is changed to `true`, it will succeed:

```java
ProtoWriteSupport.setWriteSpecsCompliant(conf, true);
```

By looking its source code, we can know this function is for setting the boolean value of `parquet.proto.writeSpecsCompliant` in the config.

In `ParquetProtoWriters.forType`'s [source code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-formats/flink-parquet/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/formats/parquet/protobuf/ParquetProtoWriters.java#L65), it create a factory with builder class `ParquetProtoWriterBuilder`, which uses `org.apache.parquet.proto.ProtoWriteSupport` internally. I guess you can somehow assign it with a correctly configured `ProtoWriteSupport` to it.

---

I also install this Python tool: https://pypi.org/project/parquet-tools/ to inspect parquet files. List fields generated in older format will be like:

```
...
############ Column(f2) ############
name: f2
path: f1.f2
...
```

and in newer format will be like:

```
...
############ Column(element) ############
name: element
path: f1.f2.list.element
...
```

Hope this article could give you some direction.

#### References

- https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/54e53e5d7794d383529dd30746378f19a12afd58/LogicalTypes.md#nested-types
- https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/pull/51
- https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/pull/463